# Springfox swagger not working in spring boot 2.2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger-2.0, springfox

I want to upgrade spring boot v2.1.9 to 2.2.0. But after the upgrade I am getting some exceptions, which says spring fox is using an older version of spring-plugin-core.

Is there any alternate solution for this or do I need to give up the springfox plugin?

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsManager.createContextBuilder(DocumentationPluginsManager.java:152)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;

The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/regosa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/regosa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry
```

maven dependency tree file :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gayvvVe_VsB1P2Hi2rcwRw8NdK89qtbq/view

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxxxx.business.workflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxx-component-workflow-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>xxxxx-component-workflow-starter</name>
    <description>xxxxx-component-workflow-starter</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jaxb-runtime.version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</jaxb-runtime.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M1</spring-cloud.version>
       <zeebe-version>0.20.1</zeebe-version>    
        <google-guava.version>27.0.1-jre</google-guava.version>
        <xxxxx.version>1.0</xxxxx.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <json.version>20180813</json.version>
        <slf4j-api.version>1.7.25</slf4j-api.version>
        <mysql.version>8.0.11</mysql.version>
        <mongo-java-driver.version>3.10.1</mongo-java-driver.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-pool2.version>2.5.0</commons-pool2.version>
        <redis.version>3.1.0</redis.version>
        <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>
        <velocity-tools.version>2.0</velocity-tools.version>
        <logstash-logback-encoder.version>5.3</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.6</httpclient.version>
        <jaxb-runtime.version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</jaxb-runtime.version>
        <env>local</env>
    </properties>   

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Start: Spring Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Spring Libraries -->

        <!-- Adding JAXB Runtime since it is not shipped with JDK 9+ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start: xxxxx Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-entity</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-redis</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-mongo</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-util</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.model</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-model</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-common-service</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-common-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-common-security</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>           
        <!-- End: xxxxx Libraries -->

        <!--  Adding Zeebe client as part of the Spring Startup -->     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zeebe</groupId>
            <artifactId>zeebe-client-java</artifactId>
            <version>${zeebe-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${google-guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logstash Log Encoder -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId> 
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId> 
            <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version> 
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongo-java-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-pool2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>${redis.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start: Swagger Libraries -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Swagger Libraries -->

        <!-- Start: Spring Boot and Security Test Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Spring Boot and Security Test Libraries -->

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>xxxxx-component-workflow-starter</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>${env}-build.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Automatic-Module-Name>com.xxxxx.business.workflow.component.starter</Automatic-Module-Name>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 
</project>
```

Comment: what exception ?

Comment: @ShaileshChandra I updated the question. Actually swagger uses old spring-plugin-core (1.2 V) but spring boot 2.2.0 uses v2.0.

Comment: can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: @earandap  I updated the pom file and also maven dependency tree

Comment: just updated my sample project from spring boot 2.1.x to 2.o, didn't face any issue, can you share your swagger config

Comment: just checked my dependency tree and I guess you are right bout spring-plugin-core version, however, I can't find out what jar is bringing spring-plugin-core-2.0 in your dependency tree

Comment: @ShaileshChandra  if you use the only swagger with spring boot its not problem, just add spring-data-JPA, spring-data-redis, then the issue will come. because these  plugins are using spring-plugin-core 2.0 wherever swagger using 1.2

Comment: my application works and pom.xml still resolving to spring-plugin-core 1.2

Comment: Springfox is dead and not supporting spring boot >2.1.9

Comment: If you are using Spring Security, use the security configuration mentioned on **[Cannot open Swagger UI in tis Version 3 in my Spring Boot Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073519/cannot-open-swagger-ui-in-tis-version-3-in-my-spring-boot-example)** page.

Answer (score 17):

**Fixed!!!**

The issue exists as spring fox libraries internally depend on spring-plugin-core:1.2.0 but it actually requires spring-plugin-core:2.0.0. This dependency correction seems to be missing in the SNAPSHOT version of the swagger libraries for supporting web flux.

We **just need to correct Maven dependencies** as given below and no code change is required:

- Maven POM Dependencies fix

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-spring-webflux</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

- Swagger Configuration:  (Same as before just for reference)

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2WebFlux
    public class SwaggerConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Docket api(final TypeResolver typeResolver) {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it helps someone I am using springboot with 2.2.8.RELEASE and below swagger version: implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0'         implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0'

----
2.9.2 version of swagger was not working.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `SpringFox 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT` with `Spring Boot 2.2.X`

- Since it is a SNAPSHOT version, it is not published in the official repository of maven and needs to be pulled from jcenter-snapshots
- `@EnableSwagger2` is removed and changed to `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc` and `@EnableSwagger2WebFlux`

**Maven**

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Repository**

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

**Sample Configuration**

```
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    //...
}
```

References

1. [Springfox docs](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#springfox-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot)
2. https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

**Note:** It seems `SpringFox` is [not dead](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932#issuecomment-571119936).

Comment: 3.0.0 was released. SNAPSHOT no longer needed

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, since `SpringFox` is abandoned and its last version is no long compatible with Spring Boot 2.2.X, you will have to look for alternatives (see issue reported in Github [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932)).

One possible option is to use `OpenAPI docs`. For that you need to remove the `SpringFox`dependencies and add these:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
              <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
              <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also, you will have to remove the `Swagger` configuration class and provide this:

```
    @Configuration
    public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components())
                .info(new Info().title("Contact Application API").description(
                        "This is a sample Spring Boot RESTful service using springdoc-openapi and OpenAPI 3."));
    }
}
```

In my case, everything seems to work with the exception of the JPA Rest repositories that are not being exposed. I will update this answer with a fix, if I find one.

These are some of the links I was checking to fix this:

- [Documenting Spring Boot REST APIs with Open API](https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/spring/documenting-spring-boot-rest-api-springdoc-openapi-3/)
- [Spring Boot OpenAPI in GitHub](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi)

Comment: who is using isEnabled, why do we need this config?

Comment: You can ignore it, it was a flag that I used to disable the former Swagger. I have removed from the code sample

Comment: still doesnt work for me in spring boot 2.2, it seems swagger-resources are not served from webjars https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293380/spring-boot-2-2-cannot-serve-swagger-resources-when-used-with-springdoc-openapi

Comment: OpenApi works as a replacement for a monolithic app, but it cannot replace the flexibility of springfox in MSOA

Comment: Why do you say that SpringFox is abandoned? It's quite alive. Just lagging behind a bit. See https://springfox.github.io/springfox/

Comment: Last version of springfox is from one year ago. It is abandoned. I will migrate to springdoc openapi soon.. Springfox is not following spring updates, you can't use it with lazy configuration and component-indexer.

Comment: If it helps someone I am using springboot with `2.2.8.RELEASE` and below swagger version:
        `implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0'
        implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0'`
And it is working fine.

Comment: Was facing similar issue with swagger 2.9.2 version.

Answer (score 5):

I upgraded to Springfox Swagger2 to 3.0.0 version and spring plugin code to 2.0.0.RELEASE version. It worked for me.

- Spring Boot Version - 2.3.9.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: My problem started after include this dependency:
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
this solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am using spring-boot 2.2.2.RELEASE and there was no issue with **spring-core** and **swagger**. Below import was the culprit

```
spring-boot-starter-data-rest
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove HATEOS dependency, but add only swagger. It works

```
//  Using only the swagger as of now, since hateos is not updated the fix for Spring 2.1.X and above
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this issue while configuring swagger dependencies with the version of 3.0.0 instead of 2.9.2 with Spring-boot 2.3.4-RELEASE version.

Finally, I did it and documented with proper steps to follow. Kindly visit [SWAGGER CONFIGURATION](https://github.com/Nallamachu/SwaggerConfiguration) page.

Answer (score 0):

As [nitin-techyplanet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59910211/265954) has already answered, the `spring-plugin-core` dependency is resolved with the wrong version `1.2.0.RELEASE`. In order to force usage of the correct `2.0.0.RELEASE`, you have to EITHER exclude the wrong transitive dependency and specify the correct one, as he/she suggested, OR to pin (!) that dependency version in your `pom.xml`. This is done in the `<dependenciesManagement>` block, not in the `<dependencies>` block. Example:

```
<spring-plugin-core.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring-plugin-core.version>
<springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
...

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- API Documentation -->
    <!-- Fix wrong resolved `spring-plugin-core` dependency version for springfox -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-plugin-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <!-- API Documentation -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue with `springfox-swagger` in `Spring Boot 2.4.x`.

What worked for me was replacing the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

With the `springdoc-openapi-ui`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The auto-generated API documentation then can be accessed at: `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`

Answer (score 0):

Using dependencies as below it will resolve the error.

for gradle : `implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"`

[image: for gradle : implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"]

for maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image: for maven use below]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by following these steps:

##### 1. Downgrade Spring Boot to use 2.4.x version.

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

##### 2. Change version for SpringFox dependencies.

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```